Suspended Ethereum in a smart contract
I sent 0.3 eth from my metamsk wallet to below address
0x076BB6117750e80AD570D98891B68da86C203A88
which is related to derive dex.
But the asset has not been transferred to my account in derive, and according to the derive support team, it is stuck in a smart contract at the following address
https://arbiscan.io/address/0x076BB6117750e80AD570D98891B68da86C203A88
and it is currently under the authority of the creator of the smart contract at the following address
0x09572935af645fA82F67673FAB0928b2Aa01835b
Please suggest me a way to recover my assets and return them to my Metamask wallet.
Transaction ID : 0xcd35704a5d3499b641ca78c4eb8cfd1275ef20a6c2953c53cd30c01fe7546ffb
Tranaction Hash : 0xd0a0a48cd6a9ba099a3919e1ca085da98dbc37fe24a76ef1b6998cb6d2afd465

Unfortunately there's nothing you can do. The ETH is completely stuck since there's no function to withdraw it. Indeed the only functions present in the contract allow to withdraw only ETH sent along the tx with msg.value, not the ETH already in the contract.
To be honest, the devs did a mistake by writing the receive() function. So maybe you can ask them for a compensation.
